# File path error in Applescript/TextExpander

Tags: applescript, path

I use the following code to open my dropbox folder quickly using textexpander.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set f to POSIX file "/Users/MrT/Dropbox"
    open f
end tell
```

Which works, but then I want to go deeper in my folders using this code. It does not work.
It looks like Textexapnder does not recognize spaces in file paths.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set f to POSIX file "/Users/MrT/Dropbox/School/Hardvard/6-Fall Session 2013"
    open f
end tell
```

Comment: Works here, are you sure the path is correct (e.g. Hard*v*ard instead of Harvard)? Instead of TextExpander, you can also use AppleScript Editor to test the snippet directly.

Comment: @patrix Yes I am sure, I copy pasted the path from the GetInfo. Still not working

Comment: It works on Applescript, but not in TextExpander

Comment: Just for testing purposes: Can you rename your Dropbox path on your drive to not include any spaces (and adjust the TE code accordingly) and try again?

Comment: I tested without space and without space+no "-" character
Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I might be totally off track, but give this a try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set f to "Users/MrT/Dropbox/School/Hardvard/6-Fall Session 2013"
    set a to POSIX file f
    open a
end tell
```

If that fails to work, change it to the following:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set f to "Macintosh HD:Users:MrT:Dropbox:School:Hardvard:6-Fall Session 2013"
    set a to POSIX file f
    open a
end tell
```